# integrating g729 on pjsip for android

Tags: android, webrtc, chromium, pjsip, g729

I am using [this](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Intel_IPP_Codecs#MacOSXInstructions) tutorial for building pjsip .Now I want to integrate pjsip with g729 codec for android.

In the above link, as there are note mentioned I have download intell IPP from standard link.

```
Download Intel IPP and Intel IPP samples from ​http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp and ​https://registrationcenter.intel.com/en/
Extract the archive to a temporary folder
Run the installer (e.g. ./install.sh) and follow the on screen instructions. The default installation options will install it to "/opt/intel/ipp/" directory (e.g. "/opt/intel/ipp/5.3.1.062/ia32/" in my case).
Extract IPP samples to a directory (e.g. to "~/Desktop/ipp-samples").
```

In /opt/intel/ipp/ I have no versio specific folder , i.e. instead I have only

```
 bin  components  examples  include  lib  tools
```

so I have /opt/intel/ipp/ above menstion folder .

what to do?

Most of tutorial which I found and try to implemenet it I faced 404 page not found including googlecode and even intel.

Can anyone suggest me the right way to integrate g729 codec on pjsip or webrtc for android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following link if you  do not want to add intel ipp . I have found it after along search :

```
https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder/commit/0337921f81b3e30da05dc1a019d60d8822be73ec
```